# Gear selection on 6 speed box

Tags: transmission, peugeot

Hi I have a Peugeot 308 1.6 ehdi with a six speed manual gearbox and have noticed that when selecting first or sixth gear it does not go in smoothly it can be notchy or clunky this is quite annoying as putting it in all the other gears is fine.could this be a possible gear selector problem or if its a cable can this be adjusted, any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

It could be your...

#### Synchronizer rings

Modern transmissions use synchronizer rings to make manual shifting possible without the need for double declutching.

[image: "Sincronizzatore" by A7N8X - Own work. Licensed under CC BY-SA 3.0 via Commons - https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sincronizzatore.jpg#/media/File:Sincronizzatore.jpg]

Each gear has its own synchronizer ring. These rings are subject to wear. If they are in bad condition gear synchronization doesn't work well and you have trouble putting in a certain gear.

Comment: Agreed.  This is more likely.

Comment: Just a shot in the dark: Some six speed gearboxes share the same shaft for the 1st and 6th, 2nd and 5th and 3rd and 4th gear. This _could_ be a reason why first and sixth gear are affected.

Comment: It's good logic and totally sensible.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check out your clutch. When do you feel pressure on the clutch pedal? If anything you may have a small leak in your clutch lines or the master cylinder. Mine did this too, where it was hard to get it into 1st gear. Its because my clutch wasn't disengaging all the way. So I filled it up on clutch fluid (brake fluid) and bleed the clutch and it worked fine.